# How To Check If a Variable Equals a Number Plus Another Number Using Javascript? (ex. 1, 4, 7, 10)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, operators

I am trying to set a conditional statement based on if a variable is equal to a number or that number plus another number (in my example 3 is that other number).

So in the application I am building there are rounds that increment each time a button is clicked.

What I need for my conditional is if that rounds variable is equal to

```
1, 4(1+3), 7(4+3), 10(7+3), etc
```

And so on from there. What is the best approach for this using Javascript to tell if that rounds variable is equal to one of the numbers mentioned above?

Comment: How about some simple tests with `===`?

Comment: @Pointy Do you mean do something like if(rounds == 1 || rounds == 4 || rounds == 7 || rounds == 10)? Because yes that would work, but only up to number 10, while I need to figure out a way to keep it scaling without just adding another OR to the if statement. Correct me if I'm wrong on what you meant please.

Comment: Well the values involved can be stored in *variables*; it doesn't have to just be constants. It's also not really clear what it is you mean by "rounds".

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with parameters. Have it return a boolean.

```
  function myFunction(number1, number2, number3) {
    if (number1 > number2 + number3) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  myFunction(1, 2, 3);
  //returns false
```

Comment: `return number1 > number2 + number3` would do it

Comment: Yeah try The Above Code